# Highlight the outliers area in CDF plot

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, ecdf

I am trying to highlight the area of the CDF in which the "outliers" fall in my visualization (perhaps a light red shading to differentiate the area).

Can you assist with shading the area where the "outlier" points for as per the definition above? For some reason when I try to look what the outlier definition did, I get an empty output, whether it is `print(outliers_iqr(days))` or `print(str(outliers_iqr(days)[1:-1])`. It just prints `array([], dtype=int64),`

This is my current code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

a = [389, 350, 130, 344, 392, 92, 51, 28, 309, 357, 64, 380, 332, 109, 284, 105, 
 50, 66, 156, 116, 75, 315, 155, 34, 155, 241, 320, 50, 97, 41, 274, 99, 133, 
 95, 306, 62, 187, 56, 110, 338, 102, 285, 386, 231, 238, 145, 216, 148, 105, 
 368, 176, 155, 106, 107, 36, 16, 28, 6, 322, 95, 122, 82, 64, 35, 72, 214, 
 192, 91, 117, 277, 101, 159, 96, 325, 79, 154, 314, 142, 147, 138, 48, 50, 
 178, 146, 224, 282, 141, 75, 151, 93, 135, 82, 125, 111, 49, 113, 165, 19, 
 118, 105, 92, 133, 77, 54, 72, 34]

#create CDF definition
def ecdf(data):
    n = len(data)
    x = np.sort(data)
    y = np.arange(1.0, n+1) / n
    return x, y

#Using +-1.5x IQR method for defining outliers
def outliers_iqr(ys):
    quartile_1, quartile_3 = np.percentile(ys, [25, 75])
    iqr = quartile_3 - quartile_1
    lower_bound = quartile_1 - (iqr * 1.5)
    upper_bound = quartile_3 + (iqr * 1.5)
    return np.where((ys > upper_bound) | (ys < lower_bound))

days = pd.DataFrame({"days" : a})

x, y = ecdf(days)

plt.plot(x, y, marker='.', linestyle='none') 
plt.axvline(x.mean(), color='gray', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2) #Add mean

x_m = int(x.mean())
y_m = stats.percentileofscore(days.as_matrix(), x.mean())/100.0

ax=plt.gca()
ax.annotate('(%s,%s)' % (x_m,int(y_m*100)) , xy=(x_m,y_m), 
            xytext=(10,-5), textcoords='offset points')

outliers= outliers_iqr(days) 
print(outliers_iqr(days)) #print outliers- doesn't print   
print(str(outliers_iqr(days))[1:-1]) #same

#highlight the outliers area in the CDF plot
ax.fill_between(?, ?, ?, where=?, facecolor='red', alpha=0.3) #between 0 and 1st quartile
ax.fill_between(?, ?, ?, where=?, facecolor='red', alpha=0.3) #between 3rd quartile and 1

percentiles= np.array([25,50,75])
x_p = np.percentile(days, percentiles)
y_p = percentiles/100.0

plt.plot(x_p, y_p, marker='D', color='red', linestyle='none') # Overlay quartiles

for x,y in zip(x_p, y_p):                                        
    ax.annotate('%s' % int(x), xy=(x,y), xytext=(10,-5), textcoords='offset points')

plt.xlabel('Days')
plt.ylabel('ECDF')
plt.legend(('Days', "Mean", 'Quartiles'), loc='lower right')

plt.show()
```

Comment: What criteria would define the *'"better method" for defining "outliers"'*? Without a clear problem description, this question is not useful.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I guess I am looking for more "widely used" rather than "statistically sound"

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a good place to create a poll.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest dropped that from the question since it is pretty insignificant to what I am asking :)

Comment: Did you look at any examples or similar questions? Did you try to use `fill_between`? What problem do you encounter?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest not exactly, when I try to look what the outlier definition did, I get an empty output, whether it is `print(outliers_iqr(days))` or `print(str(outliers_iqr(days)[1:-1])`. It just prints `array([], dtype=int64),`

Comment: Ok, so you have a problem with the code. That would require to provide a [mcve], which lets people reproduce your problem.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest ok updated. Both my data set functions and full code are listed

Comment: I edited your question such that the code is runnable. However, the code does not include any call to the function you apparently have a problem with, so what is the data you call that function with? Just integrate this in the [mcve] as well.

Comment: Edited. hopefully good now

Comment: In your `outliers_iqr()` function, `print(quartile_1, quartile_3, iqr, lower_bound, upper_bound)` gives `77.5 215.5 138.0 -129.5 422.5`, so your upper and lower bounds are outside of the data limits -- that's why your results are empty. Also, I think you want `fill_betweenx` rather than `fill_between`.

Comment: @ThomasKühn I would like to include the condition even though there are no outliers in this case.Here is what I did: `outliers = outliers_iqr(days) ax.fill_betweenx(days, outliers, x_p[0], where= outliers<x_p[0], facecolor='red', alpha=0.3) ax.fill_betweenx(days, x_p[2], outliers, where= outliers>x_p[2], facecolor='red', alpha=0.3)` but I am getting an error `ValueError: Input passed into argument "u'x1'"is not 1-dimensional` and I can't seem to find anything about this error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your array of outliers can be sometimes empty, you have to take care of that eventuality with an `if` statement. Also, as you just want to shade regions of your plot, you can actually use `Axes.axvspan` for that. Here an example that is somewhat modified from the original (all the plotting commands inside a function and adding a second subplot with data that actually *has* outliers):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats

a = [389, 350, 130, 344, 392, 92, 51, 28, 309, 357, 64, 380, 332, 109, 284, 105, 
 50, 66, 156, 116, 75, 315, 155, 34, 155, 241, 320, 50, 97, 41, 274, 99, 133, 
 95, 306, 62, 187, 56, 110, 338, 102, 285, 386, 231, 238, 145, 216, 148, 105, 
 368, 176, 155, 106, 107, 36, 16, 28, 6, 322, 95, 122, 82, 64, 35, 72, 214, 
 192, 91, 117, 277, 101, 159, 96, 325, 79, 154, 314, 142, 147, 138, 48, 50, 
 178, 146, 224, 282, 141, 75, 151, 93, 135, 82, 125, 111, 49, 113, 165, 19, 
 118, 105, 92, 133, 77, 54, 72, 34]


#create CDF definition
def ecdf(data):
    n = len(data)
    x = np.sort(data)
    y = np.arange(1.0, n+1) / n
    return x, y

#Using +-1.5x IQR method for defining outliers
def outliers_iqr(ys):
    quartile_1, quartile_3 = np.percentile(ys, [25, 75])
    iqr = quartile_3 - quartile_1
    lower_bound = quartile_1 - (iqr * 1.5)
    upper_bound = quartile_3 + (iqr * 1.5)

    return  np.where((ys < lower_bound)), np.where((ys > upper_bound))



def generate_plot(ax, df):

    x, y = ecdf(df)

    ax.plot(x, y, marker='.', linestyle='none') 
    ax.axvline(x.mean(), color='gray', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=2) #Add mean

    x_m = int(x.mean())
    y_m = stats.percentileofscore(df.as_matrix(), x.mean())/100.0

    ax.annotate('(%s,%s)' % (x_m,int(y_m*100)) , xy=(x_m,y_m), 
                xytext=(10,-5), textcoords='offset points')

    outliers= outliers_iqr(df.values) 

    #highlight the outliers area in the CDF plot
    for outl in outliers:
        vals = df.values[outl]
        if vals.size>0:
            ax.axvspan(np.min(vals),np.max(vals),alpha=0.5,color='red')


    percentiles= np.array([25,50,75])
    x_p = np.percentile(df, percentiles)
    y_p = percentiles/100.0

    ax.plot(x_p, y_p, marker='D', color='red', linestyle='none') # Overlay quartiles

    for x,y in zip(x_p, y_p):                                        
        ax.annotate('%s' % int(x), xy=(x,y), xytext=(10,-5), textcoords='offset points')

    ax.set_xlabel('Days')
    ax.set_ylabel('ECDF')
    ax.legend(('Days', "Mean", 'Quartiles'), loc='lower right')


fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 2, figsize=(10,5))

##original data
days = pd.DataFrame({"days" : a})
generate_plot(axes[0],days)

##fake data with outliers
b = np.concatenate([
    np.random.normal(200,50,300),
    np.random.normal(25,10,20),
    np.random.normal(375,10,20),
])
np.random.shuffle(b)
generate_plot(axes[1],pd.DataFrame({"days" : b}))

##naming the subplots
axes[0].set_title('original data')
axes[1].set_title('fake data with outliers')

plt.show()
```

The result looks like this:

[image: result of the code above]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Really appreciate the help! Note that by doing `days = pd.DataFrame({"days" : a})` you plotted a scatter plot rather than a cdf- and that indeed requires a `ax.axvspan`. It is easy to change to a cdf ie. `days = df['days'].dropna()`- but that requires an  `ax.axhspan` which is easy to adjust. Therefore I adjusted to have a `generate_cdf_plot()` definition with `ax.axhspan()` and a `generate_scatter_plot()` definition with `ax.axvspan()`, and made left graph a CDF, while right graph is a scatter plot. Thank you so much!

Comment: One point of confusion- in your graphs (and my scatter plot graphing version), what is y? it is no longer cumulative P(x) and can't be labeled ECDF..

Comment: @user8834780 I have to admit that I didn't really think about the meaning of the data. I was just trying to generate data that has outliers after your definition, so that the shading of the `axvspan` can be visualised. If it is needed, I can still give it some thought -- just let me know.

Comment: Would be great if I could understand what is it that is being plotted in the non CDF version. Since this is essentially a 1D array, all y values seem arbitrary to me unless I am misunderstanding. Coming up with what y is in this context would be great thank you!